# VMware Workstation - Range Port Forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, vmware-workstation

I am running VMware Workstation 12 . I want to forward range of ports for specifc IP called on guest to specifc Host IP and Port .

I tryed with NAT port forwarding , but it allow for only one port as shows below .

[image]

My case here is that i have application on guest that each time open a different port to connect remote server and i can connect this remote server only from specifc port on the host .

If i can forward all VM guest traffic to specific host port , it will also solve my problem .

Comment: Why not set the network to bridged instead of NAT?  BTW, your concept of what's forwarding where is backwards.  The guest is NAT'd from the host, not the other way around.  Put another way, using SOHO equipment, the guest is behind the router, while the host is on the WAN side of the router.

Comment: How can i map all guest traffic to specifc host port uses bridged on VM Workstation  ?

Comment: Why do you need to route all traffic to a single port?  That doesn't make sense.  If the network adapter of the guest is bridged, the two machines are on the same network.